# Why do stability measures work by removing one column at a time?

Tags: clustering

I am currently looking at different validation measures for clustering results that's offered in the `clValid` package in R. Looking at the documentation, I noticed that I can get *stability* measures by comparing clusters obtained through removing one column at a time.

Why do stability measures such as average distance between means (ADM) and figure of merit (FOM) rely on dropping columns and measuring the changes? As opposed to performing some sort of cross validation on the data. What's the intuition behind this?

Comment: On this site we field frequent questions about linear models in which the coefficient of one variable changes dramatically when one or more other variables are included or excluded from the model.  Your circumstance sounds like a variant of that.  For clustering methods particularly, the usefulness of dropping columns to test "stability" likely depends on details of the distance metric and even the clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data is not preprocessed carefully enough, results can *completely* change when you remove a single feature.

On the other hand, you also want the result to depend on every variable. So the results *should* change a little bit if you remove one.

So this test does indeed test for a particular (and problematic) kind of stability. And you can't detect this by CV.

Comment: What do you mean by preprocessed? Like how if you don't scale variables one feature might dominate?

Comment: For example, yes. And there is no guarantee that either of the usual scaling heuristics is "best".